# Failed to get Acknowledgement of Email Send Using Java in Android?

Tags: java, android, email

i am newbie in android.I have written this code its working fine and sending email as well but when i am pressing submit button it opens "**Choose an email Client**" on choosing "**GMAIL**"  it opens gmail account and send it and showing toast message "Sending Message" and email send to destination address successfully and i am still on "Email Screen" Is there any method to check if email has reached to destination address successfully it returns me "true" else it returns me "false" so that on the basis of that boolean value i can set empty values on all editboxes or Refresh all Textboxes.

```
    ImageView submitBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.askscreen_submit_btn);
            submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
    // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                        //GetText();
                SendEmailToAalim(email.getText().toString(),name.getText().toString(),address.getText().toString(),subject.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                        content.setText(" url exeption! ");
                    }   
                }
            });
        }
        public void SendEmailToAalim(String email,String name,String address,String subject)
        {
            if(email == null || email.length()==0)
            {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter Email Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(email.length()>0 && email!= null && !checkEmailValidity(email))
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter Correct Email Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(subject == null || subject.length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter Value in Subject",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
            }
            else if(name == null || name.length() ==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter Value in Name Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }
            else if(address == null || address.length() ==0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Please Enter Value in Address Field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(email.length()!= 0 &&  checkEmailValidity(email) == true &&subject.length()!=0 && address.length()!=0 && name.length()!=0)
            {
                Intent emailSendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                emailSendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{"abc32@yahoo.com"}); 
    emailSendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
   emailSendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    //emailSendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this will make such that when user returns to your app, your app is displayed, instead of the email app.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailSendIntent,"Choose an Email client :"));    
  }
  }
 public static boolean checkEmailValidity(CharSequence email)
 {
  return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches(); 
 }
```

Here is the Screen Shot of Email Screen.Can someone please point me what should i need to do to alert user that email has been sent and refresh the page.

[image: Email Screen]

Comment: Have you ever seen an Email program that tells you an email has "reached to destination address successfully"?

Answer (score 0):

```
try to use these ::->


final Intent intent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            "");
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            Uri.fromFile(new File("file name")));
                    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                            intent, 0);
                    ResolveInfo best = null;
                    for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
                        if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm")
                                || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase()
                                        .contains("gmail"))
                            best = info;
                    if (best != null)
                        intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName,
                                best.activityInfo.name);
                    startActivity(intent);
```